# How to add an html block across all pages (templates)?

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I have a flask-admin app with quite a number of custom templates. I want to add an html block at the top of every page in the app. The obvious solution would be to add it to every template (and don't forget to add it to any new custom templates) but I hope there might be a better solution, to specify the html I want in a single place and have all future new templates automatically have it.

Answer (score 1):

To simply insert HTML snippets into your templates you could use

{% include 'template_file.html' %}

To automatically get all new templates to use the HTML block try the jinja2 template inheritance which all of your templates would need to inherit from. [Docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#template-inheritance)

Comment: The problem is that my templates already inherit from various default flask-admin templates, so I can't break that inheritance

Comment: flask-admin uses jinja, with a base template which you can override or customize.